# thrift.jar build file path already added.but stil showing error

Tags: thrift

I already have all necessary `jar` file paths through Java build path.
But I am still getting errors like this:

```
Buildfile: /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/build.xml
init:
compile:
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/build.xml:17: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/build/classes
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:3: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:4: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:5: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:6: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:7: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:8: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:9: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:8: error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.scheme.IScheme;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:9: error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.scheme.SchemeFactory;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:10: error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.scheme.StandardScheme;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:12: error: package org.apache.thrift.scheme does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.scheme.TupleScheme;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:13: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TTupleProtocol;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:14: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:15: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.EncodingUtils;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:16: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:17: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback;
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:18: error: package org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:31: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
    [javac] import org.slf4j.Logger;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:32: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
    [javac] import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:38: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public long add(int num1, int num2) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:44: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]     public void add(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:44: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public void add(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                                                                                                                            ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:48: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]   public static class Client extends org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient implements Iface {
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:59: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]     public Client(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol prot)
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:64: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]     public Client(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol iprot, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol oprot) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:64: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]     public Client(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol iprot, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol oprot) {
    [javac]                                                                                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:68: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public long add(int num1, int num2) throws org.apache.thrift.TException
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:74: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public void send_add(int num1, int num2) throws org.apache.thrift.TException
    [javac]                                                                      ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:82: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public long recv_add() throws org.apache.thrift.TException
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:49: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public static class Factory implements org.apache.thrift.TServiceClientFactory<Client> {
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:51: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]       public Client getClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol prot) {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:54: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]       public Client getClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol iprot, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol oprot) {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:54: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]       public Client getClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol iprot, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol oprot) {
    [javac]                                                                                                     ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:93: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]   public static class AsyncClient extends org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClient implements AsyncIface {
    [javac]                                                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:106: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]     public AsyncClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager, org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) {
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:106: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]     public AsyncClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager, org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) {
    [javac]                                                                                                            ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:106: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
    [javac]     public AsyncClient(org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager, org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) {
    [javac]                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:110: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]     public void add(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException {
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:110: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac]     public void add(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler) throws org.apache.thrift.TException {
    [javac]                                                                                                                            ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:94: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]     public static class Factory implements org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientFactory<AsyncClient> {
    [javac]                                                                   ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:95: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]       private org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:96: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]       private org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory;
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:97: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]       public Factory(org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory) {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:97: error: package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist
    [javac]       public Factory(org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClientManager clientManager, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory) {
    [javac]                                                                                                           ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:101: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
    [javac]       public AsyncClient getAsyncClient(org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) {
    [javac]                                                                    ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:117: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]     public static class add_call extends org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncMethodCall {
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:120: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]       public add_call(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler, org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClient client, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) throws org.apache.thrift.TException {
    [javac]                                                                  ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticService.java:120: error: package org.apache.thrift.async does not exist
    [javac]       public add_call(int num1, int num2, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler, org.apache.thrift.async.TAsyncClient client, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolFactory protocolFactory, org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingTransport transport) throws org.apache.thrift.TException {

    [                                                                       ^


BUILD FAILED
/home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/build.xml:17: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Comment: Error log is fine, but some code could be helpful too.

Comment: Hi i hope ther is no big erros in my code....only thing this reference org.apache.thrift jar files .but i referenced through  Java build path option in properties of project....

Comment: My first line of log itself shows package org.apache.thrift does not exist
and i download jar file from this site [link]http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlibthrift091jar.html and if this one is wrong pls suggest correct site for jar downloading

Comment: @user875921 It's on maven central, together with source & javadoc:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.1/

Comment: hi wildfire i download maven.org but it getting error like   /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:3: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja/src/genjava/ArithmeticClient.java:4: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.thrift.TException;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/beeshma/Desktop/new/gaja

Comment: HI java Nerds any updates ? how do i solve this